# Half Derivative of $\tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I know how to find one of many half derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ which are,

$${D^{\frac{1}{2}}}\sin(x)=\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$$

$${D^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cos(x)=\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$$

Using these is it possible to find a half derivative for $\tan(x)$ by letting.

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

Does the Quotient rule apply for half derivatives as well?

For example,

$$D^{\frac{1}{2}}\tan(x)=\frac{D^{\frac{1}{2}}[\sin(x)]\cos(x)-D^{\frac{1}{2}}[\cos(x)]\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

As a side question, does the Product and Chain rule also apply for half derivatives, or some other form of it?

Comment: "Does the Quotient rule apply for half derivatives as well?" What do you propose such a quotient rule should look like? Also note that it's not _the_ half derivative, as the can be more than one. For instance, $\sin(x)\mapsto -\sin(x+\pi/4)$.

Comment: I will make the adjustments that you suggested

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6535.pdf) might be of interest.

Comment: You should cite the particular half-derivative you want to use.  Note that your propsed quotient rule fails even for the derivatives $D^2$ and $D^0$, so there is no reason to propose it for $D^{1/2}$.

Comment: Try put: `D[Tan[x], {x, n}]` in WolframAlfa and put to sum `n=1/2`?

Comment: GEdgar I'm very new to half derivatives and don't know any rules that comes with it, what I assume you are saying is what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Mariusz Iwaniuk I am doing this for a paper I am writing, namely for my Math Internal Assessment, I need some kind of method instead of writing it in WolframAlpha.